# different forms in a single template in meteor

Tags: javascript, meteor

I have different forms on single template and when user clicks on a button of 1st form(for eg. Continue button) it has to go to the next form and so on. Can we store all this different forms data in to a single collection?
If yes how can we achieve that? can anyone help me .Thanks in advance.
Sample code.

```
<template name="forms">
<div class="step1">
<form class="form1">
----//Code goes here//

</form>
</div>

<div class="step2">
<form class="form2">
-----//code goes here//
</form>
</div>
</template>
```

Comment: Hi, I never tried https://github.com/aldeed/meteor-autoform but it seems you can set your common collection in the quickForm call: {{> quickForm collection="Books" doc=this id="doForm" type="update"}}. So you could probably call many quickForm and use the same collection ? (saving the data form the first form and call it it after to fill the second with first datas + the new ones ?

Comment: Do you want to save each step when they pass that step or save all the steps when they finish all steps? I'll write you an answer depending on your case

Comment: I want to save each step field in to single mongo collection.

Comment: Try setting an id to your form and handling it in events:

Answer (score 0):

Try setting an id to your form and handling it in events:

```
<form id="form1" class="form1">
// Form1 code
</form>

<form id="form2" class="form2">
// Form2 code
</form>
```

and then

```
Template.foo.events({
  'submit #form1': function(event, template){
    //Handle submit
  },
  'submit #form2': function(event, template){
    //Handle submit
  }
});
```

It could technically work with the class by calling `submit .form1` and `submit .form2`.

Also, as mentioned in the comments, [aldeed:autoform](https://github.com/aldeed/meteor-autoform) is a very good package for that.